# como obtener el ID guardado en valor de un select (dropdown), obtener datos con ese ID y colocarlos en el checkout de woocommerce WORDPRESS

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, funciones, woocommerce

me podré explicar mejor aquí.

Requiero hacer un sistemita que haga cotizaciones, solo usuarios registrados pueden hacer cotizaciones(las cotizaciones funcionan como los pedidos se agregan al carrito, solo que cambié el nombre de pedido por cotización y agregar al carrito por agregar a la cotización, y los usuarios registrados pueden agregar clientes(registro).
Ya tengo integrado un login y un formulario de registro.

Ahorita tengo un dropdown en la pagina del checkout o finalizar compra, que despliega todos los usuarios, cada opción tiene el nombre del usuario y su valor tiene el "ID del cliente(esto lo obtengo con PHP)". Al seleccionar una opción del dropwdown llama a una función de javascript la cual obtiene el valor con user_id = document.getElementById("select_id").value;("select_id" es el id de mi dropdown).

y ya que tenga ese user_id, quiero buscar los datos de ese usuario con una función de PHP, espeficicamente esta  get_user_meta($user_id);

---

PROBLEMA:

### Mi problema es que no sé como pasar ese ID que obtengo con javascript para que llegue a la función de PHP y ya que obtenga los datos del usuario con esa función agregarlos a los campos del checkout o finalizar compra(que son nombre, dirección, RFC, más que nada datos de facturación), que creo que eso lo podré hacer con javascript.

Se que hay algunos plugins por ejemplo de YITH que hacen cotizaciones, pero en mi trabajo parece ser que quieren utilizar algo free.

Por razones de trabajo tengo que forzosamente usar WORDPRESS, no tengo mucho conocimiento en javascript, pero ando aprendiendo. Se que los datos pueden ser vulnerables, pero espero me puedan ayudar.

Agradezco mucho a quien pueda proporcionarme ayuda en este caso y si se tome la molestia de leerme.
Muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega lo que trataste o investigaste, revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: No puedes pasar directamente el ID a JavaScript, lo que yo te recomendaría seria que al presionar una opción del dropdown ejecutar una llamada Ajax, en esa llamada Ajax envías el id del usuario y entonces ejecutas tu función php, aquí tienes un ejemplo: https://decodecms.com/ajax-en-wordpress-de-manera-correcta/

Comment: Actualizo, ya pude hacerlo como me recomendaste, solamente que ahora que ya tengo los datos del usuario no se como enviarlos de PHP a JAVASCRIPT para asignar cada dato a los campos del checkout.